# Mathematica crashes with NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

I am trying to evaluate the following numerical integration

```
func[x_, y_] := (2 I (-3 Sqrt[1 - 4/t] t + 2 (2 + t) ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - 4/t]]))/t^3 /. t -> x^2 - y^2
int[b_] := NIntegrate[I/((2 \[Pi])^2 b^4 z Sqrt[1 - z]) func[y/b, y/b Sqrt[1 - z]] (E^-y (1 + y)/4 - 1/4), {y, 2 b, \[Infinity]}, {z, 4 b^2/y^2, 1}, MinRecursion -> 15, MaxRecursion -> 15, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
```

When I call `int[1]`, Mathematica crashes after a few minutes, whereas `int[10^-5]` works pretty well.
There is an issue for values of the parameter `b` which are of order one. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: On `12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)` I get `Throw::sysexc: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[\[Ellipsis], _SystemException].` followed by `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]`

Comment: `Series[I/((2 \[Pi])^2 b^4 z Sqrt[1 - z]) func[y/b, 
   y/b Sqrt[1 - z]] (E^-y (1 + y)/4 - 1/4), {z, 1, 1}]` produces

Comment: $$ -\frac{e^{-y} \left(-y+e^y-1\right) \sqrt{z-1} \left(3 y^2 \sqrt{\frac{y^2-4 b^2}{y^2}}-4 b^2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{y^2-4 b^2}{y^2}}\right)-2 y^2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{y^2-4 b^2}{y^2}}\right)\right)}{8 \sqrt{z-1} \left(\pi ^2 y^6 \sqrt{1-z}\right)}+\frac{e^{-y} \left(-y+e^y-1\right) \sqrt{z-1} \sqrt{z-1} \left(5 y^2 \sqrt{\frac{y^2-4 b^2}{y^2}}-8 b^2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{y^2-4 b^2}{y^2}}\right)-3 y^2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{y^2-4 b^2}{y^2}}\right)\right)}{4 \pi ^2 y^6 \sqrt{1-z}}+O\left((z-1)^{3/2}\right).$$

Comment: I think this implies the divergence of the inner integral at $z=1$.